# SQL Server Deadlocks Process

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have two question..

1. I want to confirm are deadlock may happen if one session is querying a table which is locked by another session with.
2. And how do resolve the above mentioned SQL error when there are more than one computer accessing to the MSSQL Server for actions such as update and delete

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhrDf.jpg)

Comment: Yes a deadlock *could* happen, no it doesn't *always* or even most of the time. It is possible to avoid a deadlock with careful coding, but without the queries involved, their query plans, and the table and index definitions, cannot advise

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock can occur when a transaction that has started to change data, conflicts with another transaction for acquiring an exclusive lock. A blockage, even a very long one, does not necessarily lead to a deadly lock.
It is possible to eradicate any deadlock using the [banker's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker%27s_algorithm) but this leads to crippling any access conccurancy in the database, which leads to have only one user in parallel!
However, we can reduce the occurrence of deadly locks by:

1. modeling the base correctly, i.e. respecting the normal form
2. indexing tables for reading as well as updating
3. reducing the level of isoaltion of transactions
4. switching from pessimistic locking (default in SQL Server) to optimized locking
5. avoiding unnecessary transactions
6. reducing the number of requests in the explicit transaction
7. changing the sequence of processing logic in the transaction

Answer (score -2):

See the link below [Using WITH](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) For `SELECT` queries use `WITH(NOLOCK)` for `UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT` use `WITH(XLOCK)` ..

Comment: Yeah, if you [want **incorrect** results use `NOLOCK`](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And `XLOCK` hints are pointless on DML because an `XLOCK` will be taken anyway

Comment: NOLOCK can give unconsistend data. See the effects of nolock in my paper : http://mssqlserver.fr/les-dangers-du-nolock/